# ML.Net PredictionEnginePool and Multiple Input

Tags: c#, ml.net

I've looked around and it seems the recommended way of implementing a Prediction Engine in an API service is by using PredictionEnginePool. I have mine currently setup like this in ConfigureServices().

```
.ConfigureServices(services => {
     services.AddPredictionEnginePool<Input, Output>()
     .FromFile("TrainedModels/my_model.zip");
     })
```

And consumed like this:

```
var predEngine = http.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<PredictionEnginePool<Input, Output>>();            
var prediction = predEngine.Predict(input);
```

Now what I need is to allow my endpoint to consume an array data input. So far, what I've seen is through using pipelines and IDataview/transforms found at [ML.Net Multiple Predictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/machine-learning-model-predictions-ml-net#multiple-predictions)

```
IDataView predictions = predictionPipeline.Transform(inputData);
```

But how can this be done when using a PredictionEnginePool where I don't have the pipeline?
Any thoughts appreciated, there should be others that have gone through this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's what your handler might look like when using PredictionEnginePool for multiple predictions.

```cs
static async Task PredictHandler(HttpContext http)
{
    var predEnginePool = http.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<PredictionEnginePool<Input,Output>>();

    var input = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<IEnumerable<Input>>(http.Request.Body);

    var response = input.Select((x) => predEnginePool.Predict(x));

    await http.Response.WriteAsJsonAsync(response);
}
```

Assuming your request body takes in an `IEnumerable<Input>`, apply the `Predict` method from `PredictionEnginePool` using the LINQ `Select` operation. The `response` in this case will be an `IEnumerable<Output>`.